Office 2019 Pro Activation
I tried to activate Offcie 2019 through KM, & i face the following problem, any one can help me please
---------------------------------------
Installed product key detected - attempting to activate the following product:
SKU ID: 85dd8b5f-eaa4-4af3-a628-cce9e77c9a03
LICENSE NAME: Office 19, Office19ProPlus2019VL_KMS_Client_AE edition
LICENSE DESCRIPTION: Office 19, VOLUME_KMSCLIENT channel
Last 5 characters of installed product key: 6MWKP
ERROR CODE: 0xC004F074
ERROR DESCRIPTION: The Software Licensing Service reported that the product could not be activated. No Key Management Service (KMS) could be contacted. Please see the Application Event Log for additional information.
To view the activation event history run: cscript ospp.vbs /dhistorykms
NOTICE: A KB article has been detected for activation failure: 0xC004F074
FOR MORE INFORMATION PLEASE VISIT: https://support.microsoft.com/kb/2870357#Error0xC004F074
---------------------------------------


KMS Client Key can only be used in a corporate environment where there is a KMS server within your network serving the activation. If it is not automatically detected on your network - you just need to specify the KMS server name/port.

Yes, we have a KMS server and I specify it

You actually have a KMS or you downloaded a KMS? You can always use the phone activation method

Keep in mind KMS activation also has a minimum number of installs.

If you have a KMS, have you contacted your IT support or spoken with your IT admins?

Have the logs listed in the error been reviewed?

Please make sure you have installed the Office 2019 host key, the KMS host is activated and configured successfully,  then test KMS host name on client, and then set to auto-discovery

Besides, you may refer to the article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/licensing-and-activation/error-0xc004f074-activate-windows. The Event logs can also help you track the Office activate activities between KMS host and clients.
